# Transformation of random variables

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-distribution

What is the probability distribution function of the variable $y$ given by
$$y=\frac{x_1}{x_1-x_2},\quad \: x_i\ge 0,$$

given that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent and identically distributed and 
$$x_i = c+z_i,\quad i=1,2 $$
where $c$ is a real nonnegative constant and $z_i\sim\chi^2_\nu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no simple answer to this and that this distribution is going to look a bit 'ugly'.  What you could do is

1. Calculate the distribution of the difference $z_1-z_2$ using a [convolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html).
2. Calculate the distribution of the sum $z_1+c$ using a change of variable.
3. Calculate the distribution of the [ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution) $\dfrac{z_1+c}{z_1-z_2}$.

You can take a look at this R code to figure out how the density looks like.

```
z1 = rchisq(10000,10)
z2 = rchisq(10000,10)
c = 10
y = (z1+c)/(z1-z2)
hist(y)
plot(density(y))
```

Best wishes.

Comment: Let me just add that Chapter I of An Intermediate Course in Probability by Allan Gut is a great reference in case you feel unsure about how to perform steps 1 and 3.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/4e73306fe17075eabf05c6b7dc4ff06f) is a Python gist attempting a similar visualization.